# Need electrical schematic of this component

Tags: converter, electrical

For my graduation project I need this converter but I would like to have the electrical schematic.

[image]

---

This is the link to the store where I bought the part.
That's all I know.

I have looked up the chip number and this is the only schematic that I found, components do not correspond with those visible in the picture:
[image]

[enter link description here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1-23V-30V-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Module-LM2596-Power-Supply-Output-dc-dc/32885025475.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dzeOaX8)

---

I tried reproducing the pcb in multisim, did not work.
If I assume that the schematic is correct the problem lies with the module.

Comment: You haven't even told us the part number of the product and you want us to give you the schematic! Did you look for the datasheet for the chip which is clearly labelled?

Comment: so, why are you asking us rather than whoever sold you this converter PCB? Have you tried anything like googling the name of the central component (LM2596S)?

Comment: By the way, I would recommend against using this very converter board in my graduation project. The LM2596S is a Texas Instruments chip  (formerly National Semiconductor). The chip depicted has no Texas (nor the National Semiconductor) logo on it. It's most certainly a counterfeit chip. You're basing the non-frying of your graduation project on something that might or might not work as intended.

Comment: Google for the datasheet of the LM2596.  That will contain a basic functional circuit for the LM2596.  From that, you should be able to work out the circuit of the board you have.

Comment: The circuit you posted almost certainly is the same as the module circuit.  I see a couple of 220uF capacitors, a 330uH inductor, a 10k variable resistor, an SS54 diode, and of course the LM2596 on your module.  All straight out of that schematic you posted.

Comment: Robbe, you've given me the impression that you are a cat inside a house, at midnight, running around, causing a mess everywhere. I think it's time to take the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) and just at least try to understand how this site works. Or you can continue running around and maybe crack some flower pots onto the ground. We love a mess.

Comment: The one difference I see is an additional diode, probably there to protect against connecting the module with the power connections backwards.

Comment: You bought the part? Then you maybe still have it and can check with your own hands, eyes and tools what it has got.

Answer (score 3):

> ... components do not correspond with those visible in the picture:

It looks pretty darn close to me:

[image: annotated photograph]

What more do you need?

---

Note that the component I've marked C3 may actually be a diode (overvoltage and/or reverse polarity protection?), and the pads next to it might be for a capacitor. Also, the empty pads next to C2 would be for C4, which is marked as "not fitted" in the schematic.

Comment: "C3" is an SMT version of the 1N4004, a shunt 1A diode on the input in case of reverse voltage, most likely.